# how to change the size of tableView in tableView controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I have created a split view controller i want to reduce the size of the table view but it has built  in tableView Controller so is there any way to change the size of the table from code mean i have only 4 rows and it gets all the side in splitViewController i want to reduce the size of tableViewController.
In My Root controller it is tableViewController so any way to solve this issue.

I have also attached the image below the image of table in that it has only three records so i want it must show only three line it is showing empty lines also.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the height of each row in this delegate method of UITableView:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Once you set the height you'll have to `reload` your table.

**EDIT:**

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: can you please explain how to fix this and will it fix this issue

Comment: its just changin cell height not the table hieght

Comment: @NaziaJan : you want to remove those extra white lines which are coming?

Comment: @NaziaJan just change your UITableView style to UITableViewStyleGrouped

Comment: @NaziaJan I've edited my answer. Add the code I've mentioned in viewDidLoad and check.

Comment: thanks Rishi i want to ask one thing we give background image to tableView but it also show extra side grey bg how to hide in grouped tableView

Comment: @NaziaJan it's not possible in group style.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code. This will not show extra lines in your `UITableView`

```
- (void) addFooter
{
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    [self.myTableView setTableFooterView:v];

    [v release];
}
```

You can also set height of your row by this

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  //Set height according to your condition
  if (indexPath.row == 0)
  {
  }
  else
  {
  }
}
```

and then you can reload your `UITableView`

```
[tableview reloadData];
```

**EDIT:** call function `addFooter` in `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

and you can add this also

```
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     // This will create a "invisible" footer
     return 0.01f;
 }
```

Comment: where to call add Footer method and after which code may i reloadData

Comment: if you set height of that function in delegate method, then no need to reload tableview, only if you are to load contents of your tableview then you can use reload from any function.